# How do i default check a radio button in react?

Tags: reactjs, radio-button, map-function

I am trying to default check the first radio button which the following code helps me to do. When loaded the page the first radio button is checked but the problem i am facing is that it doesn't allow me to check the other buttons that also are present in the array.

```
constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selectedSort: '',
            sort: ['Apple', 'Orange '],
        }
    }
this.state.sort.map((sortType:string, index:number) => {
     return <span key={`${sortType}${index}` onClick={() => this.setSort(sortType)} >
     <input type="radio" id={sortType} 
            value={this.state.selectedSort} 
           name={sortType} defaultChecked={index===0} 
           }/>
          <span>{sortType}</span>
                               
                                    })
 private setSort = (selectedSort: string) => {
        this.setState({
            selectedSort: selectedSort
        });
}
```

Comment: The `name` attribute should be the name of the radio button group, the `id` should be unique to a specific radio input. You are using the same value for both, so you've no groups. Can you provide a more complete component code example so we can see what the state is and how it's updated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Issue

The `defaultChecked` value is a boolean but your condition `sortType === 0` will always evaluate `false` since your `sortType` is only ever one of your `sort` state values, i.e. `["Apple", "Orange "]`.

## Solution

If you want the first radio button to be default checked then you should compare against the mapped index.

```
defaultChecked={index === 0}
```

## Other Issues & Suggestions

1. Radio button group inputs should all have the same `name` attribute.
2. Use a semantic `label` to wrap your inputs so they are more accessible.
3. Use the radio input's `onChange` event callback versus an `onClick`, to update state.
4. The `sortType` values alone should be sufficient for a React key.

Code:

```
{this.state.sort.map((sortType, index) => (
  <label key={sortType}>
    <input
      type="radio"
      id={sortType}
      value={selectedSort}
      name="sortType"
      defaultChecked={index === 0}
      onChange={(e) => this.setState({ selectedSort: e.target.id })}
    />
    {sortType}
  </label>
))}
```

Additionally, I suggest converting this to a fully controlled input since you have already all the parts for it. Remove the `value` attribute and use the `checked` prop. Set what you want the initial checked state to be. This will allow you have have already valid checked state.

```
state = {
  selectedSort: 'Apple',
  sort: ['Apple', 'Orange '],
}

{this.state.sort.map((sortType, index) => (
  <label key={sortType}>
    <input
      type="radio"
      id={sortType}
      name="sortType"
      checked={sortType === this.state.selectedSort}
      onChange={(e) => this.setState({ selectedSort: e.target.id })}
    />
    {sortType}
  </label>
))}
```

## Demo

[image: Edit how-do-i-default-check-a-radio-button-in-react]

Comment: I am sorry i had tried it with two condition and have sort of mixed up the two.  I tried first defaultChecked ={sortType ==="Apple"} and another was this defaultChecked={index === 0}. The problem i am facing is that it does not allow me to deselect the radio button for apple and select the radio button for the orange at all .

Comment: @Mero, See my #1 additional issue & suggestion, you need to fix the `name` attribute. Give all the inputs of the group the ***same*** `name` and they will handle deselecting when you choose another option.

Comment: The value configuration does not really make sense. I'd recommend you remove the id attribute and set value={sortType} then set selectedSort: e.target.value